# Getting hostname during SSR

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core-2.0, server-side-rendering

I am writing an app which has a client and an api at different domains, something like this:

[local]

localhost:5000 (client)

localhost:5001 (api)

[web]

app.domain.com (client)

api.domain.com (api)

Now, when writing my fetch requests, I'd like to be able to send requests to the localhost api when I make requests from the localhost client, and the web api when requested from the web client. To do this, I have to be able to set my base url, so I am trying to write a getApiDomain method which I can use to pick the right domain.

```
let fetchTask = fetch(`${Domain.getApiDomain()}/api/Item/${id}`)...
```

My method looks like this:

```
export abstract class Domain {
    public static isLocalhost = Boolean(window.location.hostname === 'localhost' );

    public static getApiDomain(): string {

        return this.isLocalhost
            ? "http://localhost:5001"
            : "http://api.domain.com";
    }
}
```

This works well for the client, but I can't get it to work on the server during SSR due to the use of window. How can I get the hostname while executing on the server?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things you can do, but the easiest would be:

For things that don't change between requests you could use the `globals` object in NodeJS. So on server startup you could detect if you are on localhost or not (maybe with a CLI flag) and do `global.settings.ApiDomain = <URL>`.

Then in your `index.js` file you could do:

```
window.settings.ApiDomain = window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ? 
  "http://localhost:5001" : "http://api.domain.com"
```

Then whenever you need to use ApiDomain you can do:

```
const apiDomain = window ? window.settings.ApiDomain : global.settings.ApiDomain
```